# Using local MongoDB instead of minimongo in a new Meteor app development

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Is it possible to start a new Meteor project using a local instance of regular MongoDB in place of the default minimongo?

If so, how?

Comment: Minimongo is the browser only version of mongodb. Do you mean you want to have a client side only collection? or to use a custom mongodb server instead of the one built in with meteor

Comment: In my dev machine I have MongoDB installed and I would like to start my new app using it instead of minimongo.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The mongodb running with meteor is still the standard mongodb, minimongo is only the client side implementation of this that allows the browser side to make queries to a collection.

Start meteor like this with your terminal as mentioned on the [unofficial meteor faq](https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq)

```
MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/database meteor
```

**EDIT:**

You can read about this in `projectdir/.meteor/local/build/README`:

> This is a Meteor application bundle. It has only one dependency,
>   node.js (with the 'fibers' package). To run the application:
>
> ```
> $ npm install fibers@1.0.0
> $ export MONGO_URL='mongodb://user:password@host:port/databasename'
> $ export ROOT_URL='http://example.com'
> $ export MAIL_URL='smtp://user:password@mailhost:port/'
> $ node main.js
> ```
>
> Use the PORT environment variable to set the port where the 
>   application will listen. The default is 80, but that
>   will require root on most systems.
>
> Find out more about Meteor at meteor.com.

Comment: But in this case why when you install meteor mongodb is also installed with it - but you don't get a system message that there is a dependent package needed to be installed (from the package manager or whatever..)

Comment: Meteor includes fibers, fibers is needed manually while making a node.js bundle for the use on external servers as a nodejs app, mongodb is also not included in this bundled version created with http://docs.meteor.com/#meteorbundle

Answer (score 0):

If you have mongodb already installed just run Meteor project with command

```
MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/meteorprojectname meteor run
```

I found the answer [here](http://meteor.hromnik.com/blog/meteor-run-without-creating-local-mongo-database)